# Looking for a good text parsing library for C#

Tags: c#, excel, file-io, csv

Has anyone run across a quality library that will parse, line by line, CSV, tab-delimited, and Excel files?

I've started to do it manually but have noticed some of the intricacies in parsing a comma-delimited file.  Such as situations where a cell has a comma in it as part of the data (blah,\"LastName, Jr.\",blah,blah).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CSV : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [FileHelpers Library](http://www.filehelpers.com/). It's free and has a number of examples on their page.

Comment: +1 I've used FileHelpers and was happy with the results.

Comment: Does FileHelpers require the input to have the structure of the file being known beforehand?  I ask because of the classes being created in the examples. In my case, I can take an upload with 10 columns in one run, then later an upload with 15 columns. It varies like that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

It will allow you to parse any type of file. All you have to do is create a mapping describing the file. Plus its free!